# samtools view -F option appears to not be functioning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, optional-parameters, samtools

Samtools version:
samtools 1.13
Using htslib 1.13+ds

##### Please describe your environment.

- Windows CPU running Ubuntu 22.04.3 environment
- machine architecture (run `uname -m` on Linux/Mac OS or  `wmic os get OSArchitecture` on Windows)
- ^ result from ubuntu cmd: x86_64
- ^ Result from windows cmd:
  OSArchitecture
  64-bit
- gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0

Hi,
I am trying to separate a bam/sam file based on directionality of reads. Samtools does not have a way to do this from an aligned sam/bam file to a reference sequence that I can find. My attempted workaround was to use samtools view -F or -f options to attempt to separate reads based on alignment flags. I am using the -o option because I need an output to occur if any changes are to happen. The big issue I am running into is that it would appear that my commands are not doing anything at all.

$samtools view -o -F aligned-input.bam
No output message of any kind, no error, no new file produced in my file explorer, no modifications to the existing file in my file explorer

Similarly, the -f version did the same thing:
$samtools view -o -f aligned-input.bam
No output message of any kind, no error, no new file produced in my file explorer, no modifications to the existing file in my file explorer

I tried the verbose version of the command:
$samtools view -o --require-flags aligned-input.bam
No output message or error, this one did produce a new output file, but it's not a SAM or BAM file, it's just listed as file type "file", and its name is "--require-flags," clearly indicating that that option did not function as intended.

Same thing for the other verbose version:
$samtools view -o --excl-flags aligned-input.bam
No output message or error, this one did produce a new output file, but it's not a SAM or BAM file, it's just listed as file type "file", and its name is "--excl-flags," clearly indicating that that option did not function as intended.

I tried to specify a flag (just to try to get it to do anything) in multiple different ways:
$samtools view -o -f 0x4 aligned-input.bam
Output in return: "[E::hts_open_format] Failed to open file "0x4" : No such file or directory
samtools view: failed to open "0x4" for reading: No such file or directory"

^This same output happens no matter what tag I try, whether in hexidecimal format or octadecimal formatting, and it also does the same thing for -F and -f.

How do I get the $samtools view -o -F (or -f) aligned-input.bam to do something? Alternatively, if I am barking up the wrong tree, does anyone have a good idea on how to separate a .bam or .sam file based on flags.
Thank you for your time, and I hope to get an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Answered on github 'issues' for samtools: https://github.com/samtools/samtools/issues/1994#issuecomment-1952477530

> Flipping the order changes nothing. It was the lack of a parameter that mattered. `-o FILE -F FLAG`, not `-o -F` or `-F -o`.